# Use stylesheet to convert xml and populate first sheet of an excel

Tags: java, xml, excel, xslt

I have an xml file and a stylesheet that perfectly populates an existing excel ( .xls ) file with xml data. But if I have multiple sheets in the given excel file, (all the remaining tabs except the first one which is to be populated ) disappear after the transformation by the stylesheet.

I think there is something that needs to be mentioned in the stylesheet to say - change only the first sheet of excel ?

I am using [java.xml.transform](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj89MTjmJzPAhUI0iYKHeVTByQQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjavax%2Fxml%2Ftransform%2Fpackage-summary.html&usg=AFQjCNH4479NNiKcAJiPAtmiyRJa2n1AXw&sig2=FdA8lOWZZO1A8u8VCxVa_Q) package to let the stylesheet do its work.

Sample code is :

```
StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer( stylesource );
Source source = new DOMSource( document );

Result outputTarget = new StreamResult( new File( outputFile ) );
transformer.transform( source, outputTarget );
```

And my stylesheet's beginning line if needed looks like :

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 

xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. An XSLT stylesheet does **not** "populate an existing excel file". It reads the input XML file and transforms it into a **new** document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That is not true. You do know that java's transform like the one in code shown above takes a `Streamresult` and transforms it, yes it overrides existing content.

Comment: I know nothing of the sort.